# W2ui row expand showing loader only

Tags: javascript, plugins, w2ui

I found this plugin: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/grid

I follow the related guide to, create a table with row expands,but when I click on expand row it showing a loader only, it is not expanding.

How can I solve this?

Comment: jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Ajay_Nair/6v3yqxz1/16/

Answer (score 0):

w2ui 1.5 no longer officially supports subgrids (or expandable records), even though the `onExpand` event is still documented.

According to the owner of w2ui, you're supposed to use tree-like grids instead, see: http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!grid/grid-7

If you still want to use subgrids, you'll have to tweak the CSS, e.g. by explicitely setting the height of the container in the expand event handler:

```
      onExpand: function (event) {
            $('#'+event.box_id).css({height: "100px"}).html('<div style="padding: 10px; height: 100px">Expanded content</div>');
        },
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fh9jpu5q/

More details: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/1160

Comment: I created a subgrid, but there is a problem when we scroll fastly, the expanded grids are getting hidden.

Comment: I created a grid with 20 columns of fixed size

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. If my answer answers your initial post, feel free to accept it. If you have further questions, please create a new question on StackOverflow.